# Opening itms-service from Flutter

Tags: flutter

I use the enterprise distribution from Apple for our app. Now I'm creating a simple update system which starts the installation of a new app version.

Therefore I need to call:
`var _url ="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://my-url-to-the-plist"`

I have done the same in other frameworks (Adobe AIR) with no problem.
In Flutter I use the `url_launcher` package with no success. The Urls scheme seems not to be supported by Flutter?

Any Ideas to this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `launch(_url,universalLinksOnly:false))` will do it on the device itself.